Can I use the Cambridge in Advanced English certificate as a proof of knowledge of English for the purpose of applying for the British Citizenship?
From the page Apply for citizenship if you have indefinite leave to remain or 'settled status' I read that I must prove my knowledge of English.
In June 2017, I passed the exam for the Certificate in Advanced English qualification for the C1 CEFR level, and I wondering whether I can use it as a proof of my knowledge of the English language.
From that latter link above I read that

If your qualification has run out
Some recognised test qualifications only last for 2 years.
If you have a B1, B2, C1 or C2 level qualification, you may be able to use it after it has run out if either:

you’re applying for citizenship
you’re applying to settle in the UK


which would support my hypothesis that I can use my certificate.
Furthermore, the "Your exam page" on my account on https://candidates.cambridgeenglish.org/ has a link to Send your results to an education institution, employer or immigration authority. If I click on that and even select UK  Visas and Immigration as the recipent (see screenshot below), which feels appropriate.
Is that what I should do?

The reason I'm in doubt is the first part of the linked page, where I read that

You can only use English for Speakers of Other Languages (ESOL) qualifications if they’re on the list of approved tests. You cannot use other qualifications, for example GCSEs, A levels or National Vocational Qualifications (NVQs).

which doesn't really mention the Cambridge exams. Even the linked page shows it in the list.

Were you able to use it at the end?

I've sent it, but it's still marked as unread. I ended up paying for the required test, which will prove sufficient.

I couldn’t categorically establish a yes or a no, however the guidance on KOLL and Assessing the English language requirement might help
